# PHP If File Exists except Certain Name

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

here is my php code to check if a file exists in my uploaded files directory.

```
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $exists = "1";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

And here is the code that makes the variable ($target_file).

```
$target_dir = "upload_dir/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

I want to be able to filter out every file that is the same, except for 1 file name, that would be the default file name for all iOS devices, "image.jpeg". Plus, maybe give me room to add in other file names for later use. :D thank's in advance!

Comment: What's the question/problem? Wrap your code with the `if(!file_exists($target_file))` conditional.

Comment: I am still a bit new to php, will you show me @mkaatam ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you're trying to do, but I think you need to wrap your logic with the negative conditional so that it will only execute if the file doesn't exist.

```
if (!file_exists($target_file) || $target_file == 'image.jpeg') {
  $target_dir = "upload_dir/";
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
  $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
}
```

Comment: I want to exclude all other file names from being uploaded if they already exist, except for 1 file name. I want that 1 file name to be uploaded numerous times

Comment: See updated answer. If the file doesn't exist or the file is the file you want to upload numerous times

Comment: Example: user x wants to upload "hi.jpg", user y wants to upload "image.jpeg". Someone else comes along and uploads another file with the name "hi.jpg", not uploadable, file already exists. However, someone else comes by to upload "image.jpeg", allow it, that's standard name for all iOS pictures. So allow "image.jpeg" to be uploaded multiple times.

Comment: Ah, OK. Let me try that :D